# Stuck using terminal while trying to configure MySql and Php

Tags: php, mysql, bash, apache, terminal

I am currently following a tutorial on lynda.com which is explaining how to set up php and my sql using apache.

I now have a major issue that i can not seem to get around. Somewhere in the process of copying the tutorial i have entered something wrong and it wont let me type any normal commands.

When i load up terminal this appears:

```
Last login: Sat Sep 16 00:20:47 on ttys000
-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: touch: No such file or directory
Tom$
```

Previously i was entering commands like this:

```
Tom$ sudo apachectl configtest
Tom$ sudo nano httpd.conf
```

Everything worked and seemed fine, but i now appear to be stuck in this bash thing that i don't quite understand and each time i type anything it says "no such file or directory". Is there anyway i can get this back to normal? I have tried a number of things but nothing seems to work.

I hope this has been clear and any help this this topic would be much appreciated!

Comment: You probably messed up your `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.environment` or the respective files in `/etc` when you tried to modify the path. You can run commands by giving their full paths like `/usr/bin/sudo` or `/usr/sbin/apachectl` until you fix it.

Comment: Edit your `.bashrc` from the GUI and remove the bad `export` line. Then logout and log back in.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.